# Any advice on how to tackle this inequality? ($x^{a}e^{x+c}\leq b$ )

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, lambert-w

How might one go about solving the inequality:

$x^{a}e^{x+c}\leq b$

where $a,b,c$ are arbitrary constants ($b\geq 0$ and $a\neq0$) for $x$.

My first place would  be to try and get all of the variables I am solving for on one side, but this problem evades such tactics.

Comment: Numerically. There isn't a closed form solution in algebraic terms.

Comment: why are you asking that ? are you searching for approximations of the (incomplete) Gamma function ?

Comment: @user1952009 I just wanted to see if it was solvable algebraically. (A passage in a textbook implied that it could be "solved".)

Comment: Would a solution using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) be acceptable to you as an "algebraic solution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "algebraic solution" if you allow the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Examples) which is defined by

$$y=W(x)\iff ye^y=x$$

Let's solve the equality. I'll ignore the multiple-branch issue here which is equivalent to saying there may be two answers or none rather than just one.

$$\begin{align}
x^ae^{x+c} &= b \\[1.5ex]
x^ae^x &= be^{-c} \\[1.5ex]
xe^{x/a} &= b^{1/a}e^{-c/a} \\[1.5ex]
\frac xa e^{x/a} &= \frac{b^{1/a}e^{-c/a}}a \\[1.5ex]
\frac xa &= W\left(\frac{b^{1/a}e^{-c/a}}a\right) \\[1.5ex]
x &= aW\left(\frac{b^{1/a}e^{-c/a}}a\right)
\end{align}$$

There may be zero, one, or two solutions to that equality, depending on the value inside the $W$ function. Those solutions will divide the real number line into intervals, some of which may satisfy your inequality.

If that kind of solution interests you, let me know and I'll flesh out the rest of the solution.